# Method that returns different types?

Tags: java, collections, iterator

I'm writing a method.

This is the Hierarchy tree:

```
IProtocoll
|
|--ProtocolImpl1
|
|--ProtocolImpl2
|
|--ProtocolImpl3
```

The method itself looks like this:

```
public static List<IProtocol> getProtocolsByType(String type, Transaction trx) {
    Iterator<IProtocol> protocols = trx.getProtocols();
    List<IProtocol> protocolsList = new ArrayList<IProtocol>();
    while (protocols.hasNext()) {
        if (StringHeper.isEqual(protocolls.next().getProtocolType(), type) {
            protocolsList.add(protocolls.next());
        }
    }
    return protocolsList
}
```

And the usage example.

```
List<IProtocol> list = ProtocolHelper.getrProtocolsByType("PROTOCOL1", trx)

for (IProtocol protocol : list) {
    ProtocolHelper.createProtocolType1((ProtocolImpl1) protocol)
}
```

Now - as seen in the type hierarchy - there are 3 possibilities of what this method could return.

`String type` is defining what type of protocols shall be returned. `trx.getProtocols()` will return an Iterator containing ALL 3 types of protocol.

Is there a way of somehow unifying this method that it will return one of those 3 types, without using unnecessary casting later while using that method?

Comment: If you feel the need to cast an object with interface type to its implementation, that should ring alarm bells. It is possible that your abstraction is incorrect and by changing the interface you can avoid the cast altogether. (Of course this isn't always possible but it's worth checking.)

Comment: Just a sidenote on the code you posted: you're calling `protocolls.next()` twice within the loop and thus might skip elements. Note that `next()` will advance the iterator by one so you need to store the return value if you want to reuse that element (e.g. in the if-clause and then adding it to the list).

Answer (score 6):

You could try the following:

```
public static <T extends IProtocol> List<T> getProtocolsByType(Class<T> typeClass, Transaction trx) {    
  Iterator<IProtocol> protocols = trx.getProtocols();
  List<T> protocolsList = new ArrayList<T>();
  while( protocols.hasNext() ) {
     //call next() only once
     IProtocol p = protocols.next();

     //Check if p is an instance of typeClass or a subtype
     if ( typeClass.isAssignableFrom( p.getClass() ) {
        protocolsList.add( (T)p );
     }
   }
   return protocolsList;
}

List<ProtocolImpl1> list = ProtocolHelper.getrProtocolsByType( ProtocolImpl1.class, trx)
```

So instead of passing the type as a string you'd pass the implementation class you want to get.

The cast `(T)p` is necessary but since you check for `p` being of type `T` or a subtype this is safe.

Comment: Note that the *caller* should probably use : `List<? extends IProtocol> protocolType   = getProtocolsByType(..)`. Since the returned collection can act as a producer of `IProtocol` instances

Comment: Assigning it back to `List<T>`?

Comment: @TheLostMind if I understood the OP correctly he doesn't want to use that since you'd then have to cast to the actual type again. `List<? extends IProtocol>` would just expose the elements as type `IProtocol` but the OP seems to want `List<ProtocolImpl1>` etc.

Comment: Don't you think that the OP should call overridden methods using `IProtocol`?. If the contract for `IProtocol` and its implementing classes holds good, then the OP should do this. If he needs other methods, then probably getting a *concrete class collection* back is fine

Comment: @TheLostMind yes, that's correct. If you can use `IProtocol` only then you should definitely do that.

Answer (score 2):

Generics is the savior. Use something like this :

```
public static <T extends IProtocol> List<IProtocol> getProtocolsByType(Class<T> clazz, Transaction transaction) {    
  //do logic here
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a possible solution:

```
public <I extends IProtocol> List<I> getProtocols(Class<I> protocolClass) {
    Iterator<IProtocol> protocols = trx.getProtocols();
    List<I> protocolsList = new ArrayList<I>();
    while (protocols.hasNext()) {
      if (protocols.next().getClass().equals(protocolClass)) {
          protocolsList.add((I) protocols.next());
      }
    }
    return protocolsList;

}
```

Instead of specifying the type as a String, specify it as a class. With the above signature you won't need to cast.

The only problem with this is that the cast to I causes a warning, but since we've already checked the class type, we know it'll cast OK.

Answer (score 0):

You could use it like this:

```
List<ProtocolImpl1> list = (List<ProtocolImpl1>) ProtocolHelper.getProtocolsByType("PROTOCOL1", trx)

for (ProtocolImpl1 protocol : list) {
    ProtocolHelper.createProtocolType1(protocol)
}
```

If you also want to avoid that cast, the only way I see based on your current code is to create separate methods in ProtocolHelper:

```
List<ProtocolImpl1> getAllProtocolsOfType1(trx);
List<ProtocolImpl2> getAllProtocolsOfType2(trx);
List<ProtocolImpl3> getAllProtocolsOfType3(trx);
```

But of course that is not very scalable if the number of protocols grows.

Answer (score 0):

Try using java generics.
`public static <T extends IProtocol> List<T> getProtocolsByType`
Type T can be any type which extends IProtocol. 
Take a look on the oracle tutorials about them -> https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/
They will solve your problem.